# vbscript: replace all text inline after a search string

Tags: vbscript

I want to perform the following with vbscript but not sure how to do it.
I have a fullString, and would like to replace anything after Reference, with a new string.

```
fullString = Reference,My Name is Bob Dillan Sharpie
searchString = Reference,
replaceString= Reference,My Name is David Naver Plus

if inStr(fullString,searchString) then
' Not sure what to do here... i only know this function.  
' newString = Replace(fullString,searchString,replaceString)
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Some combination of Right, Len and InStr should do the trick:

```
fullString = "Reference,My Name is Bob Dillan Sharpie"
searchString = "Reference,"
replaceString = "My Name is David Naver Plus"

if inStr(fullString,searchString) then
    newString = Replace(fullString, _
        Right(fullString, Len(fullstring) - (InStr(fullString, searchString) + Len(searchString) - 1)), _
        replaceString)
    wscript.echo newString
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
Option Explicit
On Error GoTo 0

Dim fullString, searchString, replaceString, newString, pos 

If WScript.Arguments.Count = 1 Then
  fullString   = WScript.Arguments(0)
Else
  fullString   = "Reference,My Name is Bob Dillan Sharpie"
End If

searchString = "Reference,"
replaceString= "Reference,My Name is David Naver Plus"

pos = inStr( 1, fullString, searchString, vbTextCompare)

If pos > 0 Then
  newString = Left( fullString, pos -1) & replaceString
Else
  newString = fullString
End If

Wscript.Echo fullString & vbNewLine & newString
```

**Output**:

```
cscript D:\bat\SO\65346768.vbs
```

> ```
> Reference,My Name is Bob Dillan Sharpie
> Reference,My Name is David Naver Plus
> ```

```
cscript D:\bat\SO\65346768.vbs "Another reference,My Name is Josef Z"
```

> ```
> Another reference,My Name is Josef Z
> Another Reference,My Name is David Naver Plus
> ```

```
cscript D:\bat\SO\65346768.vbs "My Name is Josef Z"
```

> ```
> My Name is Josef Z
> My Name is Josef Z
> ```